# how retrieve record in codeigniter as table name and database name

Tags: codeigniter

```
    Model
  <?php
            class mod extends CI_Model
            {
            public function Brecht()
                    {
                    $ans=$this->db->query("select * from table1 where 
                   database=db1");
                    $ans=$ans->result_array();
                    foraech($ans as $key => $value)
                    {
                    echo $key." = ".$value;
                     }
                   }
            }
            ?>
```

i have retrieve data from MySQL using query i will write a query than database name and table name are give in query how i will fetch this record

Comment: hello sir place give me solution to get record as give database name and table name

Comment: hello give me  solution....

Comment: Have you taken the time to read the Codeigniter Userguide at all?

Comment: sometimes i get the impression those newcomer guys think there is a big man sitting behind the site and answers those asked questions :D